# Visual Studio 2022: Open CSS Isolation File via shortcut

Tags: css, visual-studio, blazor, visual-studio-2022

One of my most used VS shortcuts when working with Blazor is F7 (View.ViewCode) which toggles between the Razor file and the Razor C# code behind files.

I would also like to open the Razor CSS code behind file via a keyboard shortcut when I am in either the Razor or C# file.  I find going to the Solution Explorer and expanding to get to the CSS file a disruption to my flow.

Comment: This would be a new feature request.  Send feedback in VS to ask for it!